# Sending email to administrator on fire event OctoberCMS

Tags: email, frameworks, admin, backend, octobercms

cannot find a way to get access to backend administrator of OctoberCMS

Want to send an email each time some event fired.

For example, in my plugin after user puts new comment.

```
Mail::send('bbrand.comments:mail.newcomment', $data, function($msg){
$msg->to(System::admin(), System::admin->name());
......
})
```

Please advice. Cannot find this in docs.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try using `\Backend\Models\User`

```
<?php
Mail::send('bbrand.comments:mail.newcomment', $data, function($msg){

    // Select all backend users
    // Can filter by groups
    $admins = \Backend\Models\User::all();
    foreach($admins as $admin) {
        $msg->to($admin->email, $admin->name);
    }
});
```